# Download file using phonegap

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, download, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to download files from the server using phone gap[cordova 1.7.0], but all the plugins that I used till now are not working well. Do you know how can I do it by just using JavaScript or a good phonegap plugin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download)!

Comment: OMG !!!! I can't believe I spent 6 hours searching for something that's already provided.
Thanks a Million Simon...You really saved me.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but I have a question ... When I send the Url & path to this function, this error occurs: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. Do you know how can I solve it ?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help at all. Basically JSON.stringify() is called to send the parameters from JS to native side. Something in "url" or "filePath" has a cyclical reference which is causing problems. Sadly, I can't tell what from your code snippet.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I'll try to find it out.
Thanks a lot Simon... you are always very helpful.
Don't you have a blog or something that you share your experience at ?